# Upload file to server while storing the local path

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

I have searched and couldn't find what suite my needs.

I have a chat app(Webview), where i would like users to upload files to server. Currently, after selecting the file, i copy the file to apps folder and then read the file to base64 before it's been uploaded to server using javascript.

```
var intent={
    action:"android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"
        , type:'video/*'
  }
 android.activity.startActivityForResult(intent,function(r){ 
//from here i copy the file to app's folder...then convert to base64 before it's sent to server

  },true);   
 }
```

The issue is with videos, i need to upload large files and converting to base64 is not the best option as it will cause device to go out memory.

So i decided to use
`<input type="file">` 
but the issue is i can't get the selected file path (Security reasons according to what i read on  stackoverflow).

I need the file path so i can store it and reference it (because the sender shouldn't be downloading the same file on his/her phone again).
The receiver will only have the server file url on his/her end and download.

At least i have seen chat app(Telegram) upload large files in chat and i can't fathom how they implemented it?

Comment: But why does the server demand that you upload already big video files base64 encoded and hence yet bigger? Yet more bytes.  Makes no sense. Upload a file as it is. Just the bytes of the file.

Comment: Further i do not understand that you first make a copy before you base64 encode that copy. You could better base64 encode the original directly. Well.. if you have to upload base64 encoded..

Comment: it is not compulsorily base64, but the issue is how to create a copy of the file into app's folder (if i'm using <input type="file">so i can reference it for the sender

Comment: @blackapps please can you suggest how big chat apps implemented it...Not the code but how they did it.

Comment: If you do not have to upload base64 encoded then upload the selected file as is. I do not understand that the issue would be to copy the file as you do not need to make a copy first as you can upload the original directly.

Comment: How do i get the  path of the selected file

Comment: You do not need a path as you get a nice uri.